# PHP - Check if a string contains any of the chars in another string

Tags: php, string

How can I check if a string contains any of the chars in another string with PHP?

```
$a = "asd";
$b = "ds";
if (if_first_string_contains_any_of_the_chars_in_second_string($a, $b)) {
    echo "Yep!";
}
```

So in this case, it should echo, since ASD contains both a D and an S.

I want to do this **without regexes**.

Comment: Use [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split them into arrays, then [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to identify the matching characters

Comment: @MarkBaker Sounds great, can you show in an answer please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it using

```
$a = "asd";
$b = "ds";
if (strpbrk($a, $b) !== FALSE)
    echo 'Found it';
else
    echo "nope!";
```

For more info check : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php

Second parameter is `case sensitive`.

Comment: That is just awesome afaik.

Comment: Also `strcspn` which will essentially return string position of the first illegal character or `false` if none exist. Instead of the initial string part up to the first illegal character that is.

Answer (score 1):

+1 @hardik solanki. Also, you can use [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) ( count/percent of matching chars in both strings).

```
$a = "asd";
$b = "ds";
if (similar_text($a, $b)) {
  echo "Yep!";
}
```

> Note: function is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **str_split** function here, then just have a look at the given links:
this might help you,

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_str_split
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp

Answer (score 0):

try to use strpos
. Hope it helpful